# <?=$str?> vs <?echo $str;?>

Tags: php, оптимизация

Что быстрее:

```
<?=$str?>
<?=$str;?>
<?echo $str?>
<?echo $str;?>
<?php echo $str?>
<?php echo $str;?>
```

Или какие-то другие варианты?

---

Согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php) «=» — синоним «echo». А значит,

```
<?echo $str?>
```

эквивалентно:

```
<?=$str?>
```

Но нужна ли точка с запятой интерпретатору для оптимизации скорости? И вообще постоянно включать и выключать анализатор — затратно?

Важность этого вопроса: что обязательно нужно интерпретатору языка для ускорения, а не какой именно способ вывода ему требуется (лично я не вижу даже предпосылок замены echo). Например, $arr[str] гораздо медленнее, чем $arr['str'] т. к. интерпретатору нужны кавычки для работы со строками.

Comment: Думаю, не дубликат - там heredoc замеряли.

Answer (score 9):

Одинаково.

Настоятельно не рекомендую забивать голову такого рода вопросами. К реальной оптимизации вопросы вида "как написать" не имеют ни малейшего отношения.

С точки зрения удобства и совместимости лучшим вариантом является

```
<?=$str?>
```

Важность этого вопроса, к сожалению, не понята автором вопроса. интерпретатору для ускорения не нужно ничего: он и так быстрый. Все что ему нужно - это отсутствие ошибок синтаксиса. Например, `$arr[str]` - это ошибка, а `$arr['str']` - это правильный синтаксис, т. к. интерпретатору нужны кавычки для работы со строками. Ошибок в коде, действительно быть не должно. Но к скорости работы это не имеет ни малейшего отношения.

Дублем этот вопрос не является, но поскольку автор вопроса не понимает, что в его формулировке вопрос не имеет смысла, то пусть вопрос остается закрытым. Все равно никакой пользы автору он не принесет.

Comment: `и совместимости` совместимости с чем?

Comment: Например, с популярными CSC

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $str;?>
```

По моему это самое наилучшее, т.к. будет при всех условиях работать, но я часто пользуюсь:

```
<?=$str?>
```

Потому что удобнее.

Comment: php 5.3 уже давно умер